# Why do I only iterate up to sqrt(N) in the problem below?

Tags: algorithm, math

**Summary of problem**

> Suppose there are five men and a monkey on an island. During the
>   night, one man woke up and divided gathered coconuts into five piles
>   and took his share and hid it. One coconut was left over and was given to the
>   monkey.
>
> A second man woke up and did the same thing. After dividing the
>   coconuts into five piles, he hid his share and one coconut was left over which he gave to
>   the monkey. The third, fourth, and fifth man followed exactly the same
>   procedure. The next morning, they divided the remaining coconuts into
>   five equal shares. This time no coconuts were leftover.
>
> If we know the number of coconuts that were gathered, what is the
>   maximum number of persons (and one monkey) that could have been in the
>   island if the same procedure occurs?

Note that the above is my personal abstraction. The full problem is available [here](https://onlinejudge.org/external/6/616.pdf).

**Summary of my solution**

I will apply the following procedure: (`N` is the number of coconuts gathered and `d` is the maximum number of people possible to do the above procedure in the problem summary)

1. Set number `d = sqrt(N - 1) + 1`
2. Given number `d`, calculate `N-1` and get the new value of `N`, which can be gotten using this formula: `N = (N-1)/((N-1)/d)` **only if** `(N-1)%d == 0`. Repeat calculating this formula `d` times
3. If in step 2, the condition `(N-1)%d == 0` is not fulfilled, set number `d = d - 1` and repeat step 2
4. If step 2 succeeds repeating `d` times, check the final `N` whether or not it is divisible by `d`, i.e. `N % d == 0`. If yes, then the number `d` that was used is the solution
5. If `d == 2` and is still not a solution, then there is no solution

My full solution is available [here](https://gist.github.com/TakeNoteIAmHere/821141a0822b39e0e2191a5df211569f) and it has been accepted as answer.

**Question**

Why did I have to only pick `d` up to **sqrt(N - 1) + 1** or **ceil(sqrt(N))**? How do I know that numbers beyond `ceil(sqrt(N))` won't fulfill the condition? What's the theory behind it? (I know that I only have to repeat until `ceil(sqrt(N))` because the book said so. I tried a solution that involves picking all possible `d`s above the square root threshold but still smaller than `N` and I got TLE [time limit error].)

Comment: You shouldn't link to an external site for the problem. Please add at least a reduced version in quer question.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I've added the important parts of the problem.

Comment: perhaps you should also say what is `d` and `N` with respect to the problem.

Comment: @norok2 Added the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the reason is simple and it is inherent to the procedure.

Let's assume that you have `d = 10` people and `m = 1` monkeys.

What is the minimum number of coconuts that the last person waking up has to find to get his *fair* share? The answer is `d + m = 11`.

What is the minimum number of coconuts that the one but last person waking up has to find to get his *fair* share? Now the answer is a bit trickier if we want to get exact numbers, but in general it has to be at least `(d + m) + (d + m) = 22 = 2 * (d + m)` so that the last one can get his *fair* share after him.

Since this goes on for the number of persons, the multiplying factor in front of `(d + m)` for the first person has to be `d`.

Hence `N >= d * (d + m)`, and for `m > 0` this also holds `N >= d * d`.
Now you take `sqrt()` both sides and you get your answer.

Comment: What's the difference between the third paragraph's and fourth paragraph's questions? Did you mistype something?

Comment: @Richard sorry, corrected, one is last person, the other one is last but one.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I understand now. I'm kinda curious how you came up with that reason though. Reading it makes me understand, but thinking the **how** before getting an explanation is kinda hard for me.

Comment: I just started writing down the equations and realized that the integer constraint was easier to see bottom-up. In principle, you can come up with a similar equation starting from the first person, but it is less explicit to realize that you have to get a factor `d` for each iteration.